# How to read audit log in SharePoint 2013 online App?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

My requirement is to build an SharePoint Hosted App for Online to read audit logs. So anybody know how to read using java-script(so we can build it using NAPA also) ? If it is not possible then how to create an SharePoint App and in code behind  we can read Audit Logs?

Answer (score 1):

The audit API is not available via the Client Object Model. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557057(v=office.14).aspx

The same question 
[Can I Access the SPAuditQuery from the JavaScript Class Library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45718/can-i-access-the-spauditquery-from-the-javascript-class-library)